# WORDPRESS: wp_set_post_terms not adding tags to CPT

Tags: php, wordpress

I build a form that allow users to register sells using the frontend. I'm trying to make it pass some taxonomies that will be used to create a filter later, but even with wp_set_post_terms function the taxonomy is not being checked/tick'd at the backend when the user add/select it at the frontend.

Here is the code snippet:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
global $wp_taxonomies;
$user_id = get_current_user_id();

if(isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
    if($_POST['submitted'] == 'f16fca78e22e3f296692e5bbe0b5f7f0597a0bf9') {
        $codigo_reserva = $_POST['codigo-reserva'];
        $pax_principal = $_POST['pax-principal'];
        $tag_acomodacao = $_POST['tag-acomodacao'];
        $quantidade_pax = $_POST['quantidade-pax'];
        $check_in = $_POST['check-in'];
        $check_out = $_POST['check-out'];
        $valor_venda = $_POST['valor-venda'];

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'vendas',
            'post_title' => $codigo_reserva,
            'post_status' => 'private',
            'post_author' => $user_id,
        );

        $post_id = wp_insert_post($args);
        $post_tags = array($tag_acomodacao);
        wp_set_post_terms($post_id, $post_tags, 'acomodacao_reserva', true);

        update_field('venda_pax_principal', $pax_principal, $post_id);
        update_field('venda_pax_qtd', $quantidade_pax, $post_id);
        update_field('checkin_venda', $check_in, $post_id);
        update_field('checkout_venda', $check_out, $post_id);
        update_field('venda_valor', $valor_venda, $post_id);
    }
}
```

Everything works well except the taxonomy

Already tried to initialize $wp_taxonomies, use the explode function at the second parameter of wp_set_post_terms, pass the array as slug, and pass the array as ID

Comment: Please show the contents of `$post_tags`. Also, if your taxonomy is hierarchical, make sure you are only passing IDs, not slugs.

Comment: What is the output of $post_tags?